# JavaScript Exception handling not working as expected

Tags: javascript, exception

This is my first time working with JavaScript exceptions and exception handling in general.

OK I have the following simple code.

```
function getMonth( month ) {

    month = month -1;
    var months = [
                    "January",
                    "February",
                    "March",
                    "April",
                    "May",
                    "June",
                    "July",
                    "August",
                    "September",
                    "October",
                    "November",
                    "December"
                ];

    if( month != null ) {
        if( months.indexOf( month ) ) {
            return months[month];
        } else {
            throw "Invalid number for month";
        }
    } else {
        throw "No month provided";
    }
}
```

Basically it first checks to see if an argument was provided to the function and if not, throw and exception. Second, it checks to see if the provided number matches a valid month number and if not throw an exception.

I ran it as follows:

```
try {
    month = getMonth();
} catch( e ) {
    console.log( e );
}
```

Console does not log the exception, "No month provided". Why is this? I am currently reading about exceptions here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling#Exception_Handling_Statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats a tricky one. The Problem here is: Your Code actually never reaches the `throw` Statements, but runs through and returns normally. The reason is a bit "JavaScriptish":

On calling the function, the variable `month` is introduced (as it is within the arguments), but to this point its value is `undefined`. The statement `month -1;` then is the same as `undefined - 1` which returns an `Illegal Number` or `NaN`. (would be better if it actually threw, I agree).

Your first `if(month != null)` now resolves to `true` as `month = NaN` and `NaN != null`. The second condition returns true because `Array.indexOf` does actually return `-1` if the given value is **NOT** within the array. And `-1` is a valid value and thus resolves to `true`.

I agree again - thats all a bit counterintuitive. But hey - welcome to JavaScript. It has it's good sides, i promise ;)

Little tip: Try all those conditions and statements i posted in the console of your browser, then you gonna understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the month variable is `undefined` and it not equals `null`.

```js
try {
    month = getMonth();
    alert(month);
} catch( e ) {
    alert(e);
}


function getMonth( month ) {

    month = month -1;
    var months = [
                    "January",
                    "February",
                    "March",
                    "April",
                    "May",
                    "June",
                    "July",
                    "August",
                    "September",
                    "October",
                    "November",
                    "December"
                ];

    if( month != null ) {
        if( months.indexOf( month ) ) {
            return months[month];
        } else {
            throw "Invalid number for month";
        }
    } else {
        throw "No month provided";
    }
}
```

For more information read this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null)

Comment: Thanks. I changed the conditional to `if( month != undefined )`  it still does not throw the exception `"No month provided"`. Why?

Comment: Is the code you provided in the question exactly the same as the code you are testing? Anyway, try to change it to `if ((month != undefined) && (month != null))`